# Finding the difference between multiple arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to write a function that takes multiple arrays and returns an array of all elements that are found in only one of the arrays. For example: `([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]) returns [4]` and `([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6]) returns [4, 5, 6])`

I'm also trying to solve the problem **without** using any libraries such as lodash. I don't know if I'm on the right lines with below. Any help much appreciated.

```
const difference = (...arrays) => {
  return arrays.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.filter(ele => !cur.includes(ele)))
 }
```

Comment: what does not work with it?

Comment: I are you expecting in this case `([1,2,3] , [2,4], [5,7] )` ?

Comment: @BadPiggie [1,3,4,5,7]

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the index is equal to the last index of a flat array.

```js
const
     difference = (...arrays) => arrays
        .flat()
        .filter((v, _, a) => a.indexOf(v) === a.lastIndexOf(v));
 
console.log(difference([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4])); // [4]
console.log(difference([1, 2, 3], [2, 4], [5, 7]));          // [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```